# ragged array not letting me have differing columns

Tags: java

So Essentially I'm having a problem with this program here that is supposed to let a teacher enter how many students they want to enter scores for and then how many test score for each student - using a ragged array. Unfortunately my array does not allow any student to have a differing number of scores. I'm really not sure what im doing wrong.

`        import java.util.Scanner;

```
    public class part2
    {
       public static void main (String[] args)
  {
  //Declarations 
  int num;
  int count = 0;
  int scores = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  double average = 0;
  int check = 1;
  int each = 0;
 //Open new scanner
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);

 //Get number of students
    System.out.println("Please enter how many students you would like to enter scores for: ");
    num = kbd.nextInt();

 //Create ragged array
    int[][] ragged = new int[num][];


 //Get number of scores for each student
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        count++;
        System.out.println("For student #" + count + " how many scores do you have? ");
        scores = kbd.nextInt();

        ragged[i] = new int[scores];

    }

    count = 0;
    //Get each student's score

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        count++;
        for(int j = 0; j < scores; j++)
        {

        System.out.println("Student  #"+ count + "'s " + (j + 1) + "'st score is: " );
        each = kbd.nextInt();

        ragged[i][j] = each;
        }
    }

    //Get each student's average of scores
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        check++;
        for(int j = 0; j < scores; j++)
        {

            sum += ragged[i][j];
            average = ((double)sum / (double)scores);


        }

        System.out.println("The Average for student #" + (check - 1) + " is: " + average);

    }



    //Housekeeping
    kbd.close();
```

}
}`

Answer (score 3):

First, don't declare your local variables up front. You should generally declare them where they are (first) assigned.

If you do that, the local variables are generally declared inside a block of code, i.e. the local variables are scoped to that block and no longer available when the block ends. That will help you, because the compiler can now tell you (error message) when you use a variable value that is no longer relevant.

Like your `scores` variable. It is assigned inside a loop, and after the loop ends, it will have the *last* value, i.e. a value that is entirely useless to the rest of the code.

So, move declaration inside the loop:

```
 //Get number of scores for each student
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        count++;
        System.out.println("For student #" + count + " how many scores do you have? ");
        int scores = kbd.nextInt(); // <=== Declare it here

        ragged[i] = new int[scores];

    }
```

Now you get compile errors where you incorrectly were trying to use it. That is because in those places you need to get the value that is relevant to the row in question. If you want, you can just re-declare and initialize the variable there:

```
count = 0;
//Get each student's score

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    count++;
    int scores = ragged[i].length; // <=== Re-declare and initialize here
    for(int j = 0; j < scores; j++)
    {

    System.out.println("Student  #"+ count + "'s " + (j + 1) + "'st score is: " );
    each = kbd.nextInt();

    ragged[i][j] = each;
    }
}
```

You need to do that again one more time, and your code should be good (on the ragged part, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

there's a really simple way of doing this. You just have to access the number of scores each student have, you can do it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    count++;
    for(int j = 0; j < ragged[i].length; j++)
    {

        System.out.println("Student  #"+ count + "'s " + (j + 1) + "'st score is: " );
        each = kbd.nextInt();

        ragged[i][j] = each;
    }
}
```

the line `ragged[i].length` will access the number of elements inside each array separately and then you can have different number of scores for each student